# How to change XML Schema so that it will recognize repetitive element?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am fairly new at XML and I have a problem with the schema.

Here's what I have inside the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Receipt>
  <Customer>
    <FullName>Sammy Stevan Djap</FullName>
    <Address>Jalan Daan Mogot Raya No. 10</Address>
    <Province>Sulawesi Utara</Province>
    <City>Manado</City>
    <ZipCode>95126</ZipCode>
    <Telephone>62431862169</Telephone>
    <Memo>Barang di kirim bareng - bareng</Memo>
  </Customer>
  <Order>
    <Product>
      <Name>Afduner Botol</Name>
      <Unit>Botol</Unit>
      <Quantity>10</Quantity>
      <Price>4500</Price>
      <Total>45000</Total>
    </Product>
  </Order>
</Receipt>
```

And this is what I have in the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Receipt">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Customer">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Province" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ZipCode" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="Telephone" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
              <xs:element name="Memo" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Order">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Product">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Unit" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Quantity" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                    <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                    <xs:element name="Total" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My goal is actually to make an XML file that allows repetitive "Product" tag. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Receipt>
  <Customer>
    <FullName>Sammy Stevan Djap</FullName>
    <Address>Jalan Daan Mogot Raya No. 10</Address>
    <Province>Sulawesi Utara</Province>
    <City>Manado</City>
    <ZipCode>95126</ZipCode>
    <Telephone>62431862169</Telephone>
    <Memo>Barang di kirim bareng - bareng</Memo>
  </Customer>
  <Order>
    <Product>
      <Name>Afduner Botol</Name>
      <Unit>Botol</Unit>
      <Quantity>10</Quantity>
      <Price>4500</Price>
      <Total>45000</Total>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Alat Potong Keramik 3 in 1</Name>
      <Unit>Buah</Unit>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <Price>205000</Price>
      <Total>1025000</Total>
    </Product>
  </Order>
</Receipt>
```

Apparently my schema does not know that I will call "Product" tag repetitively. At the moment, my schema only allows 1 "Product" tag being called.

Hence, my question is do you guys know how can I change my schema so that it will allow me to add multiple "Product" tags inside the "Order" tag?

Comment: I would question some of the data types you are using. Modelling zipCode and Telephone as integers means you are likely to lose leading zeros - is that really what you want? And unsignedByte for quantity - do you really not want to allow people to order more than 255 of anything?

Answer (score 3):

Add `minOccurs="0"` and `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the `<xs:element name="Product">`  element. If you want at least one `Product`, use `minOccurs="1"`.